# display:box doesn't work in FireFox with position absolute

Tags: firefox, css

Here is the jsFiddle:

> http://jsfiddle.net/8dbQu/1/

In brief, I have such structure:

```
<div class='content'>
    <div class='column'></div>
    <div class='column'></div>
    <div class='column'></div>
</div>
```

.content is display as box

.columns have -moz-box-flex: 1;

without set .content's position to absolute everything works fine.

But when I do so, it seems the "box" style doesn't work any more...

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`display: -moz-box` triggers a XUL box (which is NOT the same thing as `display: box` (which simply doesn't exist) or `display: flexbox` (which does something completely different)).  XUL boxes cannot be absolutely positioned; if you try to position one its display value will be forced to `block`, just like a box with `display: inline` would be forced to `block` if positioned.

The way to 'fix' it is to not use XUL boxes in web code, especially not if you expect them to behave like CSS flexboxes.  Support for CSS flexbox (with `display: flexbox`) is coming to browsers in the near future.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about XUL boxes not allowing for absolute positioning. Helped me solve my problem!